# What is the equivalent of Python `getattr` in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

In python, the syntax of `getattr()` method is:

```
getattr(object, name[, default])
```

The above syntax is equivalent to:

```
object.name
```

What is the equivalent of `getattr` in Node.js?

Comment: You mean, other than using plain dot notation?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I mean a builtin method to access an object property by its name instead of dot notation.

Comment: `object[name]` ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: @zwer i like that simply works. Is it work for any object proprty. so can i do object[name](arg) for a method?

Comment: @pouya you should also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: @pouya yes you can use it for a method

Comment: @pouya - `object[name]` will get you the property `name` (or rather its value) of `object`. If that property is a function nothing stops you from calling it. It's evaluated left-to-right so you can chain as many arbitrary calls as you need.

Comment: @zwer i got my answer thanks. if you provide an answer i will aceept it.